# sql query to list all the items in a group in one record

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that will return to me all the items in a group in one record, separated by commas,from two tables, example result below,

Items table:

```
--------------------
Name    |  Group_ID
--------------------
item1   |  1
item2   |  1
item3   |  3
```

Group table:

```
--------------------
ID    |  Name
--------------------
 1    |  Group1
 3    |  Group3
```

Result i'm looking for:

```
------------------------------
GId  |  Items  
------------------------------
 1   |  item1, item2
 3   |  item3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

USE [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT group_concat(Name) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP_CONCAT and a GROUP BY

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT gr.id, GROUP_CONCAT(item.name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM  `group` gr LEFT JOIN item
ON(gr.id=item.group_id)
GROUP BY gr.id
```

This query will display groups that don't have items associated. If you don't need those groups, then the best option is @peterms

Answer (score 0):

According to your desired output and assuming that you always have at least one item per group  or if your nat interested in groups that don't have items yet you don't even need to join your tables. Just apply `GROUP_CONCAT()` to `items` table

```
SELECT group_id gid, GROUP_CONCAT(Name) items
  FROM items
 GROUP BY group_id
```

Output:

```
| GID |       ITEMS |
|-----|-------------|
|   1 | item1,item2 |
|   3 |       item3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fecd/2)** demo

Now if you need to select all groups no matter they have items or not then you have to use an outer join as in @0r10n's answer

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31c60/1)** demo for that scenario.

Comment: A join would be required if groups with no items need to be displayed.

Comment: @0R10N Agreed. But unfortunately it's unclear from OP's question. And if it's not true then unnecessary join especially outer one is much slower.